# Is there a method to make HTML5 creative "width:100%" in Google AdManger?

Tags: google-ad-manager

I am using Googl AdManager.

A client gave us **HTML5 creative**(zip file) .

I want to this creative "width:100%" .

But Google AdManager doesn't allow HTML5 creative fluid size.

https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/7046799

I tried to do "setting HTML5 creative with fixed size, and adjust size by javascript in website".

But HTML5 creative in GAM forces SafeFrame, and is generated with nested iframes.

So I think controlling size with javascript is hopeless.

Is there a method to make HTML5 creative "width:100%" in Google AdManger?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

First, I set the HTML5 zip with fixed size, and preview the creative and Inspect element.

then I found that the creative is generated "s0.2mdn.net/dfp/..." .

So I again set creative by iframe with this URL with SafeFrame free option.

thanks.